# Try to estimate pitch angle for Drone Photo

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to measure the real properties (length/area/etc) of an object from a drone photo. From what I know I should know the distortion value from the drone photo first (photo angle), and here I am still trying to write Python code to estimate the pitch angle of the drone photo.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the drone image
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/Python 290623/DJI_0151.JPG')

# Resize the image by a factor of 1
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=1, fy=1)

# Camera calibration parameters (provide your own values)
focal_length = 1000.0  # Focal length of the camera in pixels
principal_point = (resized_image.shape[1] / 2, resized_image.shape[0] / 2)  # Principal point (resized_image center)

# Intrinsic camera matrix
intrinsic_matrix = np.array([[focal_length, 0, principal_point[0]],
                             [0, focal_length, principal_point[1]],
                             [0, 0, 1]])

# Distortion coefficients (provide your own values)
distortion_coeffs = np.zeros((4, 1))

# Detect keypoints and compute descriptors
detector = cv2.ORB_create()
keypoints, descriptors = detector.detectAndCompute(resized_image, None)

# Select a reference keypoint (e.g., the first keypoint)
ref_keypoint = keypoints[0]

# Estimate the pitch angle based on the reference keypoint
ref_3D_point = np.array([[0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
ref_2D_point, _ = cv2.projectPoints(ref_3D_point, np.zeros((3, 1)), np.zeros((3, 1)), intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs)
ref_image_point = tuple(map(int, ref_2D_point[0, 0]))

dy = ref_keypoint.pt[1] - ref_image_point[1]
pitch_angle_radians = np.arctan(dy / focal_length)
pitch_angle_degrees = np.degrees(pitch_angle_radians)

# Adjust the pitch angle range from 0-90 degrees
pitch_angle_degrees = max(min(pitch_angle_degrees, 90.0), 0.0)

print("Estimated pitch angle:", pitch_angle_degrees, "degrees")

# Draw the keypoints on the image
image_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(resized_image, keypoints, None)

# Display the estimation pitch angle on the image
cv2.putText(image_with_keypoints, f"Estimated pitch angle: {pitch_angle_degrees:.2f} degrees",
            (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Show the image with keypoints and estimation pitch angle
cv2.imshow('Image with Keypoints and Pitch Angle', image_with_keypoints)

# Wait for a key press
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It's hard to guess what you are trying to do without seeing an image.